# Calculate the nth permutation of an array of characters using c#

Tags: c#, permutation

I want to write a method using c# that is Calculate the nth permutation of an array of characters and return a character array of the nth permutation without  using recursive function.
 For example

`If the array is ABC the second permutation is ACB`.Any one can help me

Comment: At first try yourself and paste your code..

Comment: this my code with recursive :

Comment: class Permute
 {



int k=0,i=0;

                 private void swap (ref char a, ref char b)
                 {
                         char temp; 
                       temp=b;
      b=a;
      a=temp;
                  }private void go (char[] list, int position,int m)//m is length of array -1
{
int i;
if (k == m)
{
if( i ==position ){
Console.Write (list);
Console.WriteLine (" ");
}else i++;
}
else
for (i = k; i <= m; i++)
{
swap (ref list[k],ref list[i]);
go (list, k+1, m);
swap (ref list[k],ref list[i]);
}
}
}

Comment: i try to get print specific permutation on screen

Answer (score 0):

Not clear enough what your permutation logic is to provide help on a non recursive algorithm.

If you want to avoid recursive function, us a loop which runs the processing logic N times.

```
public string GetPermutation(int n, string source)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                //modify source
            }
            return source;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lexicographic permutation algorithms are usually not recursive. This page has a c# variant with a way to get fast to the Nth permutation

http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-24-millionth-lexicographic-permutation/

Answer (score 0):

There is [good project on codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) about permutations and variations with or without repetitions. I guess you need in **permutations without repetition**.